# Why the array is not getting modified in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I was trying a few lines of code on IRB, and then I found that I could not modify a new array returned as a default value from a Hash. The following is an IRB session that shows in more details my situation:

```
a = Hash.new { Array.new }
#=> {}
a[2]
#=> []
a[2].push '2'
#=> ["2"]
a[2]
#=> []
a[2] = []
#=> []
a[2].push '2'
#=> ["2"]
a
#=> {2=>["2"]}
a[2].push '2'
#=> ["2", "2"]
a
#=> {2=>["2", "2"]}
```

Why I cannot modify the default value of a nonexistent key?

Comment: You need `a[2] = a[2].push 2`. Then `a => {2=>[2]}`. `a[2]` just returns the default value, so `a[2].push 2` adds `2` to the empty array, but that does not change the hash `a`.

Comment: Look at the `object_id` of `a[2]`. It's not constant, meaning that the result of the block is not inserted with the key `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block form of [`Hash#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new) is used like this:

```
b = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = Array.new}
#=> {}
b[2]
#=> []
b[2].push('2')
#=> ["2"]
b[2]
#=> ["2"]
b[3]
#=> []
b[3].push('3')
#=> ["3"]
b[3]
#=> ["3"]
```

Comment: I might be wrong but, Hash.new(Array.new) is different than Hash.new {Array.new}. Try it yourself with `#object_id`

Comment: @Kira From what I understand, what you expected is `Hash.new(Array.new)`, not the block form.

Comment: @August No, because I will have the same object for every nonexistent key.

Comment: try this: `a = Hash.new Array.new` and then `a[2] = a[2].push 1` then, print the value for ... lets say the key 33 `a[33]`. Using `Hash.new(Array.new)`, the result will be `=> [1]`

Comment: @Kira See the edit, that's what you want now, right?

Comment: That is one way to to do it, but readers should not infer that there is anything wrong with the default value given by the OP (`{ [] }`). That works fine as long as `a[2]` appears as an lvalue,. (See my answer.). One potential "gotcha" of the form you are using is that if `a = {}`, and I want to print 'hi' if `a` has a key `2`, I need to write `puts 'hi' if a.key?(2)`.  If I write `puts 'hi' if a[2]`, I've got two problems: `if a[2]` returns `[]`, a truthy value, and now `a => { 2=>[] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good observation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See [`Hash.new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-c-new). It says:

> If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and
>   the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s
>   responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

That means you have to create a block that stores key's value you pass into hash when you're creating a new or updating an existing value. Since, your hash definition doesn't store it:

```
a = Hash.new { Array.new }
```

You'll lose the value, no matter how many times you try to do this:

```
a[2].push '2' #=> ["2"]
p a #=> {}
```

what you're doing is that you're then defining a key with a default value:

```
a[2] = []
```

and then you push values:

```
a[2].push #=> ["2"]
p a #=> {2 => ["2"]}
```

To this situation, there's another way in which you can define your block to be something like this:

```
a = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Array.new }
```

or:

```
a = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
```

If you see the above block, it says: default value of the key will be an empty array and if any object is pushed into it:

```
a[2].push '2' #=> ["2"]
```

It will store that object into that array:

```
p a #=> {2=>["2"]}
```

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect.  It is true, of course that it will work with the alternative form of the default block you give, but that is not essential; it works just fine with the block used by the OP, provide `a[2]` appears as an lvalue, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Well, either an incorrect block is being passed, or the block `{ [] }` block is not being used properly. We can't say one way is correct and the other is not. Both ways are fine as long as they are used properly. I think you should have said that if `{ [] }` is to be used, then you must... (i.e., lvalue), but there is another way that it could be done...

Comment: The first sentence is still not right, as it conflicts with the doc you reproduced directly below it.  The block is to return the default value. `{ [] }` (same as `{ |k| [] }`) does that. The block may also create a key-value pair (and/or do many other things), but that's optional.  The form `{ [] }` is suitable if it is used with `a[2]` on both sides of `=` or if you simply want to know what the default value is in your code.

Comment: I will say one more thing, then shut up. :-) (And I'll be deleting this comment.) There's one small thing I suggest you do. Where you say "To make it work. You'll have to define a key by default: `a[2] = []`. If you do that, there is no point having a default empty array. What you want is `a[2] = a[2]`. Now you have a value equal to the default, which could be an empty array or something else. Once that's done, you can modify `a[2]`, e.g., `a[2] << 3`. The more usual way, however, is to do it in one step: `a[2] = a[2] << 3`. Good night!

Comment: Right now I think my earlier comments are instructive. I'll check in the morning to see if they are still needed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : I was constructing what OP was trying to do with the explanation what's happening when he does: `a[2] = []`, but then yes, that won't make sense.

Comment: btw, about a week ago I enjoyed reading, "How I started my career after graduation", and referred a friend in B'Lore to it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Hey, thank you. Any suggestions you think where I have any area to improve? like writing, technical, etc? Please feel free to tell. Always excited to learn. :-)

Comment: I have a question for the person who +1'd my comment above that begins, "I will say...". What did you like about the comment, my pithy, insightful observation or just the first sentence?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem using:

```
a = Hash.new { Array.new }
```

If I execute `a[2]` it will return `[]`, because that's the default value.  It's just telling me what it is, nothing more.

Because the default is given as a block, the default value is a new empty array each time `a[x]` is invoked.  The important thing to understand is that it is merely an empty array, not tied to the hash `a` in any way.  That is, `a[2]` only answers the question, "what is the default value?"; it doesn't do anything with it. (As shown in other answers, if the block were written differently, all sorts of wondrous things could be done before returning the default value.)

Note that `Hash.new { Array.new }`, `Hash.new { [] }` and `Hash.new { |h,k| Array.new }` are all equivalent.

In order to add the key `2` to `a`, `a[2]` must be an lvalue. You have that later in your example:

```
a[2] = []
```

but if you do that there's no point to having a default. What you want to do is set `a[2]` equal to the default value:

```
a[2] = a[2]
```

(Note that if, as in this case, the return value of the block does not depend on the key, the line above is equivalent to:

```
a[2] = a[123456]
```

provided there is no key `123456`.)

That adds the key-value pair `2=>[]` to the hash, so now

```
a[2].push 2
a[2].push 3
a #=> {2=>[2, 3]}
```

It make more sense, however, to do this in one step:

```
a[2] = a[2].push 2
```

If `a` does not have a key `2`, `a[2]` on the right of the equality will equal the default value of an empty array, `2` will be pushed onto it and the value for key `2` will be set equal to `[2]`.

If `a` already has a key `2`, say `a[2] = [3,4,5]`, `a[2]` on the right will be `[3,4,5]`, `2` will be pushed onto that and `a` (if it has no keys other than `2`) will be:

```
a #=> {2=>[3,4,5,2]]}
```